# And again. Make DropDownButton opens on mouseEnter and hide when mouse leaves

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using MahApps and MVVM Light. And I want to make DropDownButton opens on mouse enter. And hide it when mouse cursor leaves button and opened menu. For code simplification, I don't write code with EventToCommand. I just write code behind

XAML

```
                <controls:DropDownButton x:Name="ddbVolume" Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding AudioControls}"
                                     Icon="{DynamicResource appbar_settings}" BorderThickness="0"
                                     ArrowVisibility="Collapsed" 
                                     Loaded="OnDropDownButtonLoaded" MouseEnter="OnDropDownButtonMouseEnter">

            </controls:DropDownButton>
```

and .cs

```
    private void OnDropDownButtonMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var dropDownButton = sender as DropDownButton;
        if (dropDownButton != null && !dropDownButton.IsExpanded)
        {
            dropDownButton.IsExpanded = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnDropDownButtonLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dropDownButton = sender as DropDownButton;
        if (dropDownButton != null)
        {
            var template = dropDownButton.Template;
            var menu = (ContextMenu)template.FindName("PART_Menu", dropDownButton);
            menu.MouseLeave += (o, args) =>
            {
                if (dropDownButton.IsExpanded && !dropDownButton.IsMouseOver && !menu.IsMouseOver)
                {
                    dropDownButton.IsExpanded = false;
                }
            };
            menu.PreviewMouseMove += (o, args) =>
            {
                if (!dropDownButton.IsExpanded)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var x = args.GetPosition(menu).X;
                var y = args.GetPosition(menu).Y;
                if (x < 0 | y < 0 | x > menu.ActualWidth | y > menu.ActualHeight)
                {
                    menu.ReleaseMouseCapture();
                }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            this._logger.Debug($"Error loading DropDownButton");
        }
```

But it does not work. The DropDownButton is only flicker on mouse over. Please, give me a proper solution, or any usefull advice to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the menu is appearing at all then your opening logic is good, but then it disappears, meaning that your own code is somehow closing it.

Stick a breakpoint on the line where you set dropDownButton.IsExpanded = false, and you'll see that's it's being called I'm sure.  You can then use the debugger to see why it's been invoked and fix the problem in your xaml that's causing the system to think that your mouse has left the menu.

Comment: the problem was that dropDownButton.IsMouseOver is always false

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should subscribe the MouseLeave Event. And you could fix your Actions.

Comment: i subscribed to it, but not for main control, yet for it's logical child control

Answer (score 0):

I have made a solution. And it works as i expect. The root of the problem was, that DropDownButton uses ContextMenu to show list items. And this control is based on Popup, which uses his own window. And MouseLeave fired not at time, when mouse coursor was not over it, but when it's lost focus.

XAML

```
                <controls:DropDownButton x:Name="ddbVolume" Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding AudioControls}"
                                     Icon="{DynamicResource appbar_settings}" BorderThickness="0"
                                     ArrowVisibility="Collapsed">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Source={x:Static commands:CommonCommands.DropDownButtonLoadedCommand}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Source={x:Static commands:CommonCommands.DropDownButtonMouseEnterCommand}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            </controls:DropDownButton>
```

And a ViewModel code (I know it's not a VM, but it works the same way)
In static class I define commands that can be used anywhere in my application.

```
 public static class CommonCommands
{
    private static ICommand dropDownButtonLoadedCommand;
    private static ICommand dropDownButtonMouseEnterCommand;

    public static ICommand DropDownButtonLoadedCommand => dropDownButtonLoadedCommand;
    public static ICommand DropDownButtonMouseEnterCommand => dropDownButtonMouseEnterCommand;

    static CommonCommands()
    {
        dropDownButtonLoadedCommand = new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(DropDownButtonLoaded, x => true);
        dropDownButtonMouseEnterCommand = new RelayCommand<MouseEventArgs>(DropDownButtonMouseEnter, x => true);
    }

    private static void DropDownButtonLoaded(RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        var dropDownButton = args.Source as DropDownButton;
        if (dropDownButton != null)
        {
            var template = dropDownButton.Template;
            var menu = (ContextMenu)template.FindName("PART_Menu", dropDownButton);
            var button = (Button)template.FindName("PART_Button", dropDownButton);
            menu.MouseLeave += (o, e) =>
            {
                if (dropDownButton.IsExpanded && !dropDownButton.IsMouseOver && !menu.IsMouseOver)
                {
                    dropDownButton.IsExpanded = false;
                }
            };
            menu.PreviewMouseMove += (o, e) =>
            {
                if (!dropDownButton.IsExpanded || !menu.IsOpen)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var x = e.GetPosition(menu).X;
                var y = e.GetPosition(menu).Y;
                if (x < 0 | y < -button.ActualHeight | x > menu.ActualWidth | y > menu.ActualHeight)
                {
                    menu.ReleaseMouseCapture();
                }
            };
        }
    }

    private static void DropDownButtonMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        var dropDownButton = args.Source as DropDownButton;
        if (dropDownButton != null && !dropDownButton.IsExpanded)
        {
            dropDownButton.IsExpanded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I know there are some little defects. For example, "expression y < -button.ActualHeight" is not good at all. the proper way is to use button.IsMouseOver in MouseLeave event.